# drop table statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on the oracle database 11gR2 by using oracleXE 11g 
I had created a test table as

```
create table test1
(
  id number(8)
);
```

then I drop table that mean the table should move to the recycle bin

```
Drop table test1;
```

Then I have tried to check if the table is exist in the recycle bin by using the command

```
select * from recyclebin;
```

but the results was no-rows selected.

According I need your help how can I find this table and also how to restore this table because I had tried to use flashback statement but the result was as feature not enable:flashback table

Comment: Maybe the recycle bin is simply disabled in your installation. `show parameter recyclebin;` will tell you. And flashback is not available in XE as far as I remember.

Comment: XE is fine, in  *Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production* the  `select value from v$parameter where name = 'recyclebin'` gives `on` and recycle bin works.

Comment: Are you doing this test using sys user or some user for which tablespace as system? Then it will not work